# OpenCV: stereoRectify results in empty image

Tags: opencv, camera

I have 2 cameras and want to calculate the disparity between them.

The translation between those cameras is mainly in z-Direction (i.e. "inside the image plane") and a little bit in x and y direction. For example: (0.2, 0.2, 0.8)

When I now calculate the rectification parameters with the `stereoRectify()` method, the output images are just black. Using other translation vectors works just fine, but the results are wrong of course.

Why is it like that and how can I solve the problem?

Edit: These translation values result in both rectified images black. Other (wrong) translation vectors work just fine. Changing the value of alpha doesn't change much.

```
rotation_quat = Quaternion(0.999999913938509, 0.00029714546497339216, -0.00011465939948083866, 0.0002658585515330323)
rotation = rotation_quat.rotation_matrix.astype(np.float64)
translation = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.8]).astype(np.float64)
R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, roi1, roi2 = cv2.stereoRectify(intrinsicMatrix1,     distCoeffs1, intrinsicMatrix2, distCoeffs2, img1.shape[::-1], rotation, translation, alpha=1)
map11, map12 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsicMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, img1.shape[::-1], cv2.CV_32FC1)
map21, map22 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsicMatrix2, distCoeffs1, R2, P2, img2.shape[::-1], cv2.CV_32FC1)

# rectify
img1_rect = cv2.remap(img1, map11, map12, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)
img2_rect = cv2.remap(img2, map21, map22, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

cv2.imshow("img1_rect", img1_rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("img2_rect", img2_rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Show your code and show your images

Comment: I added the code. I can't show the original images I use, but the resulting images are just black. Nothing more to see than zeros.